# Is there an alternative to specifying exact location of all assets like images etc, used in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website will be heavily image based and feature lots of pages, some of which will be quite deep within the hierarchy of the website. I then noticed I was beginning to have to put up to 3 or 4 iterations of ../ infront of my images location to get to the saved images folder. Is there a more streamlined, automatic way of doing this? What do other large websites do when it comes to requesting images that might be multiple levels away from the root and images folders?

Answer (score 1):

The most used and appropriate way of handling this would be creating an assets folder and having all the assets such as images in the particular folder. So create an assets folder in the same folder as you have your index.html

```
 Your Project/
├── index.html
├── css
├── assets
  ├── images
```

You can have folder inside images to group your images you wish.

Comment: I do currently have this in place, however, if I were to then have another folder of html pages and inside that another subfolder etc, that means to access the images folder I would have to go up x amount of levels to get to the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

At least from my limited experience in web development, with some backend languages like NodeJS, you can specify the root directory as the “public” or “static” directory containing all of the CSS and media. Therefore, in the HTML, when you link to the css or images, it’s just looks like this: /css/styles.css

Comment: So from anywhere else within the project folder all you'd need to do is specify /assets/images for example? no need for any ../../../ etc?

Comment: Often referred to as root relative path.

Comment: Yes, my website stores all HTML files in /views while the images are in /static/media/, but since I specified the root path as /static on the server-side, all I have to do is reference them as /media/img.png

Comment: Ah I see, is this option commonly given by webhosting companies?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if they just offer it as an option, but if you control the server-side code, I'm sure you can specify it yourself. For example, on my website, I use NodeJS on the backend and use this line of code to specify the root directory of static with all of my CSS, JS, and images: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/static')))`